# CGI open database

Tags: sql, scripting, cgi, database-server

I require a cron job to open and export a table from my DB.

My web-host's control panel has a page for cron tasks.   It requires a script to run.

I'm a .PHP & SQL guy, have never written a .CGI Script.

I would appreciate any guidance on this matter, before I waste time.  Is it even possible to run SQL commands from a .CGI script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things that you have to take care:

1. $_SERVER, $_GET, $_POST... arrays will be empty or undefined.
2. The variables environnement will be minimalist in a cron job

There is no problem to run a CGI script.

You can also try to execute it on command line.